# Why is div box not animating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myPortfolioPage").hide();
  $("#contactMeBox").hide();
  $("#gameBox").hide();

  $("#gameScrollButton").hover(function() {
    $("#gameScrollButton").addClass("pointer");
  });

  $("#gameScrollButton").click(function() {
    if (!($("#gameBox").hasClass("open"))) {
      $("#gameBox").fadeIn(1000);
      $("#gameBox").addClass("open");
    } else {
      $("#gameBox").fadeOut(1000);
      $("gameBox").removeClass("open");
    }

  });




  $(".contact").click(function() {


    if (!($("#contactMeBox").hasClass("open"))) {
      $("#contactMeBox").fadeIn(300);
      $("#contactMeBox").addClass("open");
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, 0);


    } else {
      $("#contactMeBox").fadeOut(300);
      $("#contactMeBox").removeClass("open");

    }


  });

  $(".contact").hover(function() {

    $(".contact").addClass("pointer");


  });


  //My portfolio
  $("#myPort").hover(function() {

    $("#myPort").addClass("pointer");


  });

  $("#myPort").click(function() {





    /*$("#contactMeBox").fadeOut(100);
  $("#contactMeBox").removeClass("open"); */
    $("#myPortfolioPage").fadeIn(750);
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 0);
   /* Will edit out this error $("html,").animate({
      "left": "-1375px"
    }, "slow"); */

   $("#homePage").animate({"left":"-1375px"},"slow");
//Code above in question ^^^^^^^ Thanks



  });

  //BackHome
  $(".goHome").hover(function() {

    $(".goHome").addClass("pointer");


  });

  $(".goHome").click(function() {

    $("body").animate({
      "left": "0px"
    }, 1000);
    $("#myPortfolioPage").fadeOut(500);


  });


});
```

```html
<body>  
<div id=headerBoxAfter style="border-style:solid;margin-top:-20px;height:80px;width:100%;margin-left:-3px;background-color:black;text-align:left;">
   <!-- <img id=gameScrollButton src=down56.png alt=downButton style=float:left;margin-left:12px;margin-top:3px  -->
   <h1 id=myName style=font-family:st;font-size:40px;margin-top:30px;margin-left:20px;> <span style=background-color:white;border-style:solid;padding:10px;>My</span>  <span style=background-color:red;border-style:solid;padding:10px;margin-left:-35px;>Name</span> <span id=myPort style=color:white;> My Portfolio </span> </h1>
   
  </div>
  
  <div id=homePage style=boder-style:solid;height:100%;padding-bottom:20px;> <!-- homePage begins -->
  
  <div id=bodyBox style=height:100%;width:100%;border-style:solid;margin-left:0px;
 </div>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="RyanTTSchultz.js"></script>
         </body>
```

I would like my whole homepage to move left when a user clicks a navigation button.

I have given my div box an id="homePage"
I have referenced it in my js as so:

```
$("#homePage").animate({"left":"-1375px"},"slow");
```

The above line worked with "html,body", but I decided I wanted to keep my header universal and just animate the things below.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show a minimal code example of what your page looks like.

Comment: There is not enough information here to help you.

Comment: If you want a real answer, we need real issue to see here. So better if you could create a similar **[demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net)** or provide enough code that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add `position:relative;` in your CSS to `#homePage`.

This markup is atrocious though - you should not have inline CSS in your HTML code, and you should be wrapping your HTML attributes in quote marks. You have unclosed `<div>` tags and seem to be adding a pointer class to any hovered items - you shouldn't need to add a class for this, you just target them in your CSS by using: `#myId:hover { /*Add styles*/}`.

On top of which your JS is invalid, as you have a comma after $('html,'). I put this in a fiddle for you, and cleaned it up a little, but I would urge you to look around at some best practice for HTML and CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/t4bp4qqm/